# AccessViolationException when moving app to server 2008R2 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, exception, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

We are switching to Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit servers and are seeing some issues. Our windows services are throwing "AccessViolationException" exception in the windows event log. We never had this issue on our old windows 2003 32bit servers. The only app change was a recompile as a 64bit app.

I don't know if it's a code issue, or a server setup issue. Anyone have any ideas why this would happen?

**Update:**

Here are two of the stack traces:

```
Application: MyApplication1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:

   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel)
   at MyApplication.AlertWorkerBase.persistErrors(System.String, System.String, Char)
   at MyApplication.AlertWorkerBase.StartAlertWorker()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()


Application: MyApplication2.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException

Stack:
   at System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, IntPtr, Int32, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[])
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.DoCrossContextActivation(System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.IConstructionCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ClientContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.Activate(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy, System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.IConstructionCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)
   at MyApplication2.SessStatsLookup..ctor(Energy.VT.Common.ApplicationParameters)
   at MyApplication2.TCPConnection.ClientHandler.Initialize(MyApplication2.ApplicationParameters)
   at MyApplication2.TCPConnection.ClientHandler.ServeClient()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: But the other application (MyApplication2) has nothing to do with Oracle...

Comment: Do you have any knowledge (or better yet, access to source code) for what SessStatsLookup() does, when App2 remotes out to call into the constructor for it?

Answer (score 0):

This post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/eacaf64d-09b8-4565-9cc1-91c918a31797/

discusses a buffer overflow issue being caused by the connection string being > 40 bytes. I doubt it's the same issue, but you could try the OP's work around to see if it is related:

> As workaround I will not resolve the data source in my connection
>   strings (the goal was to distribute Oracle applications without using
>   tnsnames.ora).

If your conn string is under 40 bytes, and you're still seeing the exception, I'd contact oracle and see if they have newer drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still have one app that doesn't connect to oracle at all having this issue.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like it's remoting out to something else, which may just be bubbling the Exception up to it (which could be where the actual problem is, on a remote call to SessStatsLookup() that possibly talks to Oracle?)

Comment: I am sure. The app doesn't do anything with any oracle instance.

Comment: Should I leave this answer up (did it fix one of the two apps?), or delete it?

Comment: I've setup debugdiag to see if it will give a little more info on why this is crashing. So, don't delete the answer yet.